# Number of pthread_cond_signal()s and pthread_cond_wait()s mis/match

Tags: variables, pthreads, conditional-statements

There is one Producer and n consumers.
producer us assigning n jobs to n consumers and calling pthread_cond_wait() n times to wait for the assigned job to be completed by consumers.
Each Consumer after consuming job calls pthread_cond_signal() to notify the producer.

My question is "Will n calls to pthread_cond_signal() by consumer makes the producer to come out of  pthread_cond_wait()  n times? Or is there any case where multiple signals be merged into single signal so that pthread_cond_wait() comes out less than n times?

Answer (score 0):

If the producer isn't actually waiting inside a call to `pthread_cond_wait()` when a consumer thread calls `pthread_cond_signal()`, then that signal will get 'lost' (ie., if the producer thread later rolls into the `pthread_cond_wait()`, it will block until another signal is sent).

That is why condition variables must be used in conjunction with some other "boolean predicate" that is checked while holding the mutex used with the condition variable.  That predicate is the actual final word on whether or not the thread deciding whether or not to wait should wait. Another reason that the predicate is the final word is that a thread blocked in `pthread_cond_wait()` can be spuriously awakened.

From the [POSIX docs on `pthread_cond_wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html):

> When using condition variables there is always a Boolean predicate
>   involving shared variables associated with each condition wait that is
>   true if the thread should proceed. Spurious wakeups from the
>   pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait() functions may occur.
>   Since the return from pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait()
>   does not imply anything about the value of this predicate, the
>   predicate should be re-evaluated upon such return.